# 'list' object has no attribute 'move_to'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am coding on a bot that kicks people out of the voice channel after a specific time but I am getting this error:**'list' object has no attribute 'move_to'**

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def outro(ctx,):
    #Loads opus
    #if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
    #    discord.opus.load_opus('libopus.so')


    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        #playing song
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(source_song)
        player = voice.play(source)

        channel_voice = client.get_channel(1014932059279605770) #gets the channel you want to get the list from

        members = channel_voice.members #finds members connected to the channel

        memids = [] #(list)

        for member in members:
            memids.append(member.id)

        print(memids)
        await asyncio.sleep(58)
        await memids.move_to(None)
```

I hope anyone can help me out here

Comment: `memids` is a list, and [there is no list method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) `move_to()`.

Comment: I know but how do I fix it

Comment: Remove `.move_to()`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want `memids.move_to(None)` to do?

Comment: it should kick the members from the voice channel

Answer (score 0):

meminds is a list of members ids. You probably have to get specific user by id from this list, and then kick him from channel. What library do you use?

Comment: import discord
from discord import Intents
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from requests import delete

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following that url https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2128
Channel_members return a 'discord.Member' type, so it should have the method you're looking for.

You should replace:

```
await memids.move_to(None)
```

by:

```
# idx_to_kick --> the id in the list of members that should be kicked
await members[id_to_kick].move_to(None)
```

Comment: The list error is gone now but now I get this **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple**

Comment: Your error suggests that the index you're using is a tuple instead of an int. Without seeing your updated code we can't tell you why, but double-check the argument you're using.